# Facebook user information using only an OAuth Token

Tags: facebook, oauth

Due to user error, a situation has arisen in which my database holds an Oauth token for a facebook user without that person's facebook id, proper name, or the email linked with the facebook account.  Using only the Oauth token, is it possible to get the user's facebook id or other information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token holds all the information you need - as explained by [Ben Biddington](http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/) (and probably many other places) part of the token (between the pipes (`|`)) is the session-key, in this format:

```
2.{secret}.3600.{expires_at_seconds_after_epoch}-{user_id}
```

so if your token looks something like

```
1234567890|2.3onmAQCJpDQDrbT6.3600.1307484000.0-987654321|316cKUabM1Z-5X4P8k4sJdnW8ok
```

the session-key is

```
2.3onmAQCJpDQDrbT6.3600.1307484000.0-987654321
```

and then the user id will be `987654321`

Comment: This appears to be out of date with the new Oauth2 access tokens. Is there a new way to do this?

Comment: For getting info about tokens from Facebook, they have a special service for this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#debug

Answer (score 3):

If the token's still valid, try fetching `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token=____`