# Is it possible to get any information out of a Facebook Token without hitting the server?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token

With the old Facebook access tokens (Oauth1) it was possible to [get a user's Facebook ID and the token's expiration without passing anything to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271249/facebook-user-information-using-only-an-oauth-token).

Is this possible with the new Oauth2 tokens? Is there any data you can get from the token itself?

I know you can pass at token to /me and get lots of info (assuming the token is still valid) but I am interested in if there is any way to do this exclusively on the client without a network connection and/or with expired tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - No!
You need to hit the https://graph.facebook.com/me endpoint with the access token even to get the Facebook ID, you cannot do anything with the access token on the client.